# I am looking to automate docker execution process using shell scripts

Tags: bash, docker, shell, automation, docker-container

I tried assigning variable

```
$ CONTAINER_ID = $(sudo docker run .....)
```

and then executing using

```
$ sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

But nothing happens every time I try to execute this shell script. I want to automate docker execution and not run every time the following steps:

```
$ sudo docker ps
$ sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

Any suggestions how I can grab the latest running container and then execute it.

Comment: The code you've shown looks just fine...assuming that you're including the `-d` option in your `docker run` command line (and assuming that the container has `/bin/bash`, and that it actually starts successfully). Of course, you could just give your container a name (with the `--name`) option, and then use that instead of the container id when calling `docker exec`.

Comment: So I am not detaching (-d flag) my container inside docker run. I believe that is used for prolong usage correct? It can also cause issue incase I wish to use latest container every time. Secondly yes I do have /bin/bash command in my container. So in my question if you observe the term CONTAINER_ID is name if that's what you want me to change. or are you referring to $sudo docker run -d --name? @larsks

Comment: " I believe that is used for prolong usage correct?" That is not correct. The `-d` option means "run detached and return a container id". Without that, you remain attached to the container stdout and you will not receive a container id.

Comment: Thank you @larsks! That was helpful. detaching did the trick.

Comment: How can we extract latest container id from $ sudo docker ps -l? Is there a flag we can use to detach the container and store it in a separate variable so that can be used for executing the docker?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking, but if you have additional questions you should open a new question: comments are really meant for extended discussions. I would suggest using container names rather than relying on container ids; I think that might make your scripting tasks easier.